# how to pass Command line arguments in java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

How to accept two digit number as command line argument and print the sum of its digits. If two digit number is 88 output will be 16. Here my task is to dont  use conditional or looping statements.

Comment: Either provide a more specific problem, or do more research on google.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the first string passed from the command line adding the casted integers of each digit.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(0, 1));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(1, 2));

        System.out.printf("Sum: %d", a + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use parseInt rather than valueOf.  There's no reason to box/unbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your java class should have a `main` method as such

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....YOUR CODE....
}
```

When you compile and run your class, all command line parameters will be contained in the `args` method parameter.  You can read that array to get your data and do what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

The main method in a java class takes String array as an argument and you can access your command line arguments using array index, for example

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // check for an empty array is recommended here
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(0, 1));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[0].substring(1, 2));
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass in a single String argument and cast each digit to an integer. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks Malik for pointing this out.