# CommandLine Argument acess

Tags: java, shell, maven, command

How to access command line arguments that is passed as follows?

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.test.App -Dexec.args="-Duserid=10023”
```

I've tried to receive them by

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("userid"));
```

but it returns `null`.

Comment: ... what has this code to do with command line arguments?

Comment: @N.M.N: I don't have experience with Maven, but according to [this doc](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html), the name of the property is `exec.args`, which - I suppose - will deliver to you the string _-Duserid=10023_, from which you can then extract the user id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass Command line arguments in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376759/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-java)